# how to modify the value of a jstring passed to a C++ routine using Java and JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Can I pass a string from Java to my C++ routine using JNI function calls and modify its value in the C++ routine?

So far, I have seen examples of returning jstring, which I do not want to do. The other option that I know about is to get the ID of the string variable within C++ and set its value.

At present, I am playing with a function like the following:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_myexample_ChangeString
(JNIEnv *, jobject obj, jstring strJava)
```

And I want to change strJava's value. So, essentially what I am asking is if it Java can pass variables by reference and not just by value.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us why you don't want to return a `jstring`. Why do you feel you need to modify the string in-place?

Comment: It was because I was already returning a bool from that routine. Now, I am no expert in JNI so most likely there is a better way of doing this. From one of the responses below, I understand that writing another funtion may be another option. Thanks.

Comment: Well, in that case I've changed my answer to list several ways to get more information out of a method that already has a return value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java strings are immutable by design, you cannot change them, not even with JNI.

Comment: By the way, the string is effectively being pass by reference, think of it as const.

Comment: Actually you can change String text with reflection, but it's not a good thing to do.

Comment: You can do it, but is not legal and it would raise all kind of problems. Just as you can modify const objects, which is undefined if the object was originally declared const.

Comment: Okay. How about I identify the string using the getfield of the string? Can I then set or modify its value in the C++ routine?

Comment: It can be especially dangerous to change strings if they have been interned, since you might end up changing a string that is shared in many places in the running application, not just the string you passed in.

Comment: You simply shouldn't do it. Even if you get it to work now, there are no guarantees that it will work in a different environment.

Comment: Okay, got it. I will write a function that returns a string. Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 3):

So, it seems that what you really want to do is return more than one value from a native method. There is no direct way to do this, but there are a few indirect ways:

- Instead of returning a `boolean`, create a class that contains both a `boolean` and a `String`, and have your native code create and return an instance of that class.
- Pass a one-element `String[]` as an argument, and have the native code set its string result as the first element of that array.
- Create a class with a `#setStringValue(String)` method, and pass that into your native method, which will then call that method to supply the string result. Once the native call completes, the Java code that created the helper class can extract the string value.

---

Of these possibilities, the one-element array is probably the easiest to handle from JNI code because it doesn't involve looking up additional classes or methods. However, if I wanted to return extra information from a non-native method I would probably return an instance of a new class containing both results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify a `String` parameter, as Java `String`s are immutable. What you can do however is place the string in an array, pass the array to the native code, and then in the native code (using some JNI interop methods) create a new Java `String` and replace the reference in the array with a reference to the new string:

Caller.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

// Prototype for native method.
class MyJNI {
    public static native void changeStringsNative(String[] stringArr);
}

void CallNative()
{
    String[] myStringArr = new String[1] {"Original"};
    System.out.println("Original (Java): " + myStringArr[0]);
    MyJNI.changeStringsNative(myStringArr);
    System.out.println("Changed (Java): " + myStringArr[0]);
}
```

Callee.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Helper macro so we only need to declare class name once.
#define JNIFUNCTION(sig) Java_com_mycompany_myapp_MyJNI##sig

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNIFUNCTION(changeStringsNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
    jobjectArray myStringArr))
{
    int stringCount = env->GetArrayLength(myStringArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < stringCount; i++) {
        jstring myString = (jstring)(env->GetObjectArrayElement(myStringArr, i));
        const char *myStringOriginalC = env->GetStringUTFChars(myString, NULL);
        printtf("Original (native): %s\n", myStringOriginalC);
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(myString, myStringOriginalC);
        
        // Now do something in native to transform the string. For example, a printf involving the original.
        char *myStringChangedC = NULL;
        if (asprintf(&myStringChangedC, "Different from the %s!\n", myStringOriginalC) == -1) {
            // asprintf malloc error.
            return;
        }
        printtf("Changed (native): %s\n", myChangedStringC);

        // Create a new jstring and put into the array.
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(myStringArr, i, env->NewStringUTF(myChangedStringC));

        free(myStringChangedC); // must free after asprintf's malloc.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output to stdout:

```
Original (Java): Original
Original (native): Original
Changed (native): Different from the Original!
Changed (Java): Different from the Original!
```